# 'Mainstream media' è plurale o singolare?

Tags: grammatical-number, plural

Cari amici,

riflettevo sull'uso di 'mainstream media' — che, secondo Garzanti Linguistica, sono i 'media tradizionali (contrapposti all’informazione via Internet)' — e, in particolare, riflettevo se 'sto sintagma deve intendersi al plurale o al singolare.

Ho cercato su Google Libri e ho notato che alcuni autori usano dire 'il mainstream media' (singolare 'il'), mentre altri scrivono 'nei mainstream media' (plurale 'nei').

Stante quanto sopra, tenuto conto che se plurale o singolare potrebbe pure dipendere dal contesto, sono a chiedere se nella seguente frase è più proprio usere 'nei' o 'nel'.

> È sconcertante notare come il referendum del 17 aprile sia pressoché assente **nel**/**nei** mainstream media, come non fosse neanche in programma.

Un cordiale saluto.

Comment: Personalmente, se proprio fossi costretto a usare queste due parole, direi “i media mainstream”, secondo la sintassi italiana. In italiano, con “il mainstream media” sembra che si stia parlando di un mainstream di qualche tipo specifico. Altrimenti direi “i media [o: i mezzi di comunicazione] tradizionali/convenzionali”. Ma qualche dizionario italiano riporta “mainstream media”? Sul Garzanti riesco a trovare solo la sigla “msm”.

Comment: @dag, sì, è sul Garzanti che ho letto quella definizione alla voce MSM “(mainstream media) media tradizionali (contrapposti all’informazione via Internet)”.

Comment: @dag, e, comunque, se cerchi in Google Libri, vedrai esistono molte occorrenze nei testi italiani.

Comment: @dag, dove sei? Pensavo replicassi qualcosa ai miei commenti, ciò atteso che il tuo sembrava interlocutorio.

Comment: Penso che dipenda dalla parola "media". Secondo Treccani si dice "i media" (pl) e "un medium" (singolare). Per esempio se dici: "Facebook e Twitter sono i social media più usati" appare chiaro che la parola media è plurale.

Comment: @Arcsn: penso che sia la risposta corretta. Potreste scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 6):

Penso che dipenda dalla parola "media". Secondo [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mass-media/) si dice "i media" (plurale) e "un medium" (singolare). Per esempio, se dici "Facebook e Twitter sono i social media più usati", appare chiaro che la parola "media" è plurale.